# go to [location] after login depending on variable in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login system which works. In the mysql database I have a field called medals which is pre filled in for each username and password.

The next step I want to do is redirect each user depending on their medals which is either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

so lets say a user with 1 medal logs in i want it to go to location 'page1.html'

if a user with 2 medals logs in i want it to go to location 'page2.html'

if a user with 3 medals logs in i want it to go to location 'page3.html'
and so on.

I have tried the following code but does not work

```
      // Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
        // Set username session variable
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        // Jump to secured page
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
switch ($row['medals']):
    case 1:
        header('location: page1.html');
        exit;
    case 2:
        header('location: securedpage.html');
        exit;
     case 3:
        header('location: page3.html');
        exit;
     case 4:
        header('location: page4.html');
        exit;
     case 5:
        header('location: page5.html');
        exit;
```

It is simple coding but i just cant get my head around it.

any help would be great

Comment: is your question about how to get the value from MySql? Or how to redirect to different places?

Comment: i want it redirect to different places depending on how many medals the user has. I treid your code but it is not working. 

// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
        // Set username session variable
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        // Jump to secured page
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
switch ($row['medals']):
    case 1:
        header('location: page1.html');
        exit;
    case 2:
        header('location: securedpage.html');
        exit;
     case 3:
        header('location: page3.html');
        exit;

Comment: did you ever sort this out? Its good practice to accept an answer or specify what you're still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your result has a field called "medals"

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
header('location: /page'.$row['medals'].'.html');
exit;
```

Comment: assuming of course that `medals` didn't originate from some user input and is safe to use... also, you want `mysql_fetch_assoc` here.....and `$sql` has to be a result handle, not the SQL string....

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
switch ($row['medals']):
    case 1:
        header('location: page1.html');
        exit;
    case 2:
        header('location: page2.html');
        exit;
    etc...
```

Comment: // Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
        // Set username session variable
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        // Jump to secured page
       $row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
switch ($row['medals']):
    case 1:
        header('location: page1.html');
        exit;
    case 2:
        header('location: page2.html');
        exit;
     case 3:
        header('location: page3.html');
        exit;
     case 4:
        header('location: page4.html');
        exit;
     case 5:
        header('location: page5.html');
        exit;

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row` "Returns an numerical array" (read: non-associative) http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: @user1188711 What is the error you are getting? Dump out $row after the fetch_row with var_dump($row) and post here. If your $sql is something like "SELECT medals FROM some_table", then you might need to change $row['medals'] to $row[0]. If your $sql is something like "SELECT some_other_column, medals FROM some_table", then use $row[1], etc. Then use: switch ((int) $row[0]) { .... } so that you're making sure its an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
**This would be surely useful**
$listQry = "SELECT * FROM medals INNER JOIN users on medals.usr_id = users.user_id  WHERE users.user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']."";
$listRes = mysql_query($listQry);
while($listRow = mysql_fetch_row($listRes)):
        $data[] = $listRow[0];
endwhile;


foreach($data as $k=>$v):

    switch($data[$k]):
        case 1 : header('Location: page1.html');exit;break;
        case 2 : header('Location: page2.html');exit;break;
    endswitch;

endforeach;
```

Comment: nooooooooo..........you realize you're looping over an array of data and then trying to redirect for each element? that `foreach` is pointless, it'll only ever execute once. the `break;` is also moot with that `exit`.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make that more clear. `$data` is an array, yes? You use `foreach($data as $k=>$v)` to loop over said array, and then goes into that switch and `exits` for every case. Why loop if it's going to exit on the first iteration? Unless you mean in the event that there no matches? I suspect that scenario shouldn't occur. Also, you've got `$data[$k]===$v` so you might as well use that inside your `switch()` and nevermind the `$k`.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$medal = $result['medals'];
header('Location: page' . $medal . '.html');
exit();
?>
```